# GCM new Push notification replacing old notification data in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on GCM Push notificatios, i have already managed push notification very well, i am getting push notifications from server as i want,but when android device receive same type of notification then new notification overlap all data of same previous notifications. how can i keep data of old push notification? Please suggest me best way

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: For what u need code? this question is enough clear and specific without it ... Not every question need a code to be good one

Comment: To those who marked this question as unclear: the question is perfectly clear. Prove? I found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are setting a `collapse_key`. If you use this and the receiving device is offline while sending multiple messages from your server only the last message will be delivered to the device when it comes back online.

Sending messages without the optional `collapse_key` will lead to receiving all messages on the device.

Answer (score 2):

[GCM payload](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#payload) has `collapse_key` attribute. From doc it is

*`An arbitrary string (such as "Updates Available") that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it comes back online`*

So your this is expected behavior while `collapse_key` is same into message sent from Server to GCM server.

To get rid of your problem you can change `collapse_key` for each message (**if your application needs** but this is not a good way and remember that *GCM allows a maximum of 4 different collapse keys to be used by the GCM server at any given time.*)

Comment: if they are maximum 4 then what would be the way to deliver all messages to user when user was offline for long time? I'm using multicast so obviously user will get more than 4 messages when he/she was offline.